# I can't run json file on react

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new to `react.js`.

I am following the documentation example on their [website](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

I don't really understand this portion here:

```
// tutorial11.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/api/comments" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

when I use this `comments.json` file here `<CommentBox url="comments.json" pollInterval={200} />`, it won't work. But if I rename `comments.json` file to `comments.txt`, it works perfect. I don't know what I am missing here. I hope somebody here can explain to me further how to use `.json` file.

Comment: the code is the same in their website.

Comment: *I don't know what I am missing here* - So we will try to find out, but without your code it will be more difficult

Comment: `<CommentBox url="/api/comments" />` I only wan't to know why the url porperty won't work if I use `.json` file. Everything works fine if I use `.txt` file with the same json content.

Comment: What do you have inside `componentDidMount` method?

Comment: `componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
   },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105878/discussion-between-the-and-yul757).

Comment: Are you setting `datatype` as `json` in your ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

url for commentbox is just a property which can be access via "this.props.url", to get the comment.json data use the ajax request in the lifecycle function of react js such as "ComponentDidMount".

Comment: yes I know, everything works fine if I use url="comments.txt", but won't work if I use url="comments.json". And I want to know why? Thank you for your time friend.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping, I got it working already using `<CommentBox url="db.php" pollInterval={200} />`.

The solution is just making the output as `json`.

[Here is the datail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916394/how-to-output-like-this-in-php/35916643#35916643)

Hope this helps.