# How to output like this in php

Tags: php, json

I want to achieve this output in php.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1388534400000,
        "author": "Pete Hunt",
        "text": "Hey there!"
    },
    {
        "id": 1420070400000,
        "author": "Paul O’Shannessy",
        "text": "React is *great*!"
    }
]
```

I have a `while loop` in my backend below.

```
$pull = "SELECT * FROM mydb";
    $result = $con->query($pull);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json['id'] = $row['id'];
        $json['author'] = $row['author'];
        $json['text'] = $row['text'];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

It only returns the last row in the database, and I want to display them all.

Thank you.

Comment: replace `$json['id'] = $row['id'];
        $json['author'] = $row['author'];
        $json['text'] = $row['text'];` with `$json[] = $row;`

Comment: @Mark Baker Thank you for that clever answer! Works like a charm!. You should put this as answer, not as comment.

Comment: Mark Baker has the simplest answer, govindkr13 is also helpful but, Vinie makes everything clear, that's why I choose him as the best answer. Hope you guys understand. Thank you all! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `$row` contains only these three fields from database then use below code otherwise @govindkr13 answer

```
$pull = "SELECT * FROM mydb";
$result = $con->query($pull);
$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are simply overwriting your $json array every time. Try this:

```
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $json[$i]['author'] = $row['author'];
        $json[$i]['text'] = $row['text'];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
$pull = "SELECT * FROM mydb";
$result = $con->query($pull);
$final = [];
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json['id'] = $row['id'];
    $json['author'] = $row['author'];
    $json['text'] = $row['text'];
    $final[] = $json;
}
echo json_encode($final);
```

Comment: Thank you @govindkr13, your code works. but the simplest answer is from Mark Baker above.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help.

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json[$row['id']]['author'] = $row['author'];
    $json[$row['id']]['text'] = $row['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $json[$i]['author'] = $row['author'];
        $json[$i]['text'] = $row['text'];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$count=0;
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$json[$count]['id'] = $row['id'];
$json[$count]['author'] = $row['author'];
$json[$count]['text'] = $row['text'];
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```